# What Font Awesome version is on this page?

Tags: font-awesome

I have to modify a legacy application and I want to quickly figure out what version of Font-Awesome the application is running, so I know which icons are available.

As that application is using complied CSS, I was unable to determine from the page's resources.

I imagine something like a JavaScript command or inserting an icon like `fa-version` which renders the version number.

Comment: no access to css before compilation, in any way ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try the following :

1. Locate CSS File

locate the use of a fontawesome icon in a page. Using Developper Tool (F12), find which CSS file gives the icon (and font).
In this file, search for a version number in comments (some CSS compiler keeps these comments)

2. Locate the Font file

in the previously located CSS file, search for the following string :

```
@font-face{font-family:FontAwesome;src:url(fontawesome....eot)}
```

Either the font file contains the version number, either you should go deeper.

3. Look for version in font file

Download the font file (you can guess the URL based on file name and CSS file URL)

Open the file in your favorite text editor and search for `Version`

Comment: Indeed. I went to the Style tab of the Dev-Tool and found common.css. The original is compacted to a single line, but there is a `save` function which gave it to me in human-readable. Indeed comments were still in and they told me. It loads the WOFF2 type, which does not say 'version'. Additionally I managed to find the dev-box where the application is built and under Node (?!) I found the sources of the CSS. Thanks!